# What are the subgroups of $D_9$?

Tags: group-theory

What are the subgroups of $D_9$? I've got a cayley table of $D_9$ but can't find the subgroups. any help?? I've tried highlighting the columns and rows but can't seem to find any

Comment: I doubt that one can read off the subgroups from a Cayley table except for some very simple cases. For example take any reflection $\tau$ of the 9-gon. What can you say about the subset $\{e,\tau\}$, where $e$ denotes the identity? In general to find all subgroups you have to compute within $D_9$. First find all subgroups generated by one element, that is all cyclic subgroups. Next consider subgroups generated by two elements and finally show that no other subgroups need to be considered.

Comment: Also try a smaller group like $D_5$ first and do what @HagenKnaf said. Build that intuition.

Comment: Try to search about the ways to build a **subgroup lattice diagram**.